# extract substring from end of line

Tags: bash

I got a long list of filenames, and from each filename I want to extract the substring identified by the 4th token from the back, assuming the separator is underscore like:

```
/dir1/_GET_na_na_na.txt
/dir1/dir2/_GET_na_na_na.txt
/dir1/dir2/na_GET_na_na_na.txt
/dir1/dir2/na_na_GET_na_na_na.txt
```

In all these cases I want to extract the "underscore GET underscore". I can 'basename' to get rid of the random dirname, but that still doesn't solve the problem that I need to 'cut -f4 -d_' from the back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for awk

```
awk -F_ 'NF > 3 {print FS $(NF-3) FS}' file.txt
```

Comment: You meant to write `print FS $(NF-3) FS`?

Comment: Sure, if he really wants the underscores.

Answer (score 2):

As given by the other answers, `awk`-based solutions are probably the quickest/easiest.  But since you tagged this just [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), here's a bash-only answer:

```
$ while IFS=_ read -a line; do echo "_${line[@]: -4:1}_"; done < file.txt
_GET_
_GET_
_GET_
_GET_
$
```

Simply read each line into an array, splitting on `_`.  Then output the 4th from last array element.

Comment: +1 for a _readable_ answer (to clarify: something not meant for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ) `:)`

Answer (score 1):

dirty and quick:

```
awk -F'_' '{NF-=3;print FS $NF FS}' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "    /dir1/_GET_na_na_na.txt
    /dir1/dir2/_GET_na_na_na.txt
    /dir1/dir2/na_GET_na_na_na.txt
    /dir1/dir2/na_na_GET_na_na_na.txt"|awk -F'_' '{NF-=3;print FS $NF FS}'
_GET_
_GET_
_GET_
_GET_
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one in `perl`:

```
$  perl -F_ -lane '$,="_"; print "",$F[-4],""' file.txt
_GET_
_GET_
_GET_
_GET_
```